# How to make a for loop for each vector in list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector

I have a list l, contains four vectors, each vector contains a number of elements, the vectors are not the same length.

```
l<- list(2:4,3:5,4:7,5:7)

  for ( i in length(l)){

     print(l)
   }

[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6 7

[[4]]
[1] 5 6 7
```

I would like to add value 2 to all the elements of each vector in the list using for loop.
Maybe we need (**two for loops**) The external  will be for the list and the internal will be for each vector of the list, I would like to obtain  the following result :

```
    [[1]]
    [1] 4 5 6

    [[2]]
    [1] 5 6 7

    [[3]]
    [1] 6 7 8 9

    [[4]]
    [1] 7 8 9
```

**Please note that:** the original list contains 389 vectors, each vector contains not less than  45 elements.

Comment: Just ```lapply(l, `+`, 2)```

Comment: Thanks,  Sotos  I want to use for loop only.

Comment: Why would you? for loops are often not the best choice in R; in this case, using `lapply` is the best choice

Comment: I know, The example above just for understanding the idea of for loop, the main task contains a number of conditions, I am trying to solve the task step by step, that is why I have chosen the loop.

Comment: You can do it step by step via `*apply` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much faster and cleaner way is to not use a loop. Here, we are mapping each vector `.x` in `l` to `.x + 2`.

```
purrr::map(l, ~.x + 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 5 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5 6 7
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6 7 8 9
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 7 8 9
```

If you really need the loop version, just loop through the indexes of `l` and add 2 to each vector.

```
for (i in seq_along(l)) {
  l[[i]] <- l[[i]] + 2
}
print(l)
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 5 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5 6 7
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6 7 8 9
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 7 8 9
```